Passing nullable to a Jetpack Composable
New Android developer here, I imagine I'm probably missing something fundamental...
I have a class instance which is not initialised straight away. I pass this to a composable and want to use it after it has been initialised. Something like this:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var camera: USBCamera? = null

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MyComposeUI(camera)
        }
    }

@Composable
fun MyComposeUI(camera: USBCamera?) {
    Button(onClick = { camera?.setGain(10) }) {}    
}

The problem is this doesn't work because camera is always null??
camera is initialised elsewhere (in a separate thread) and I can make this work by either accessing it using LocalContext or wrapping it in a class. (Please feel free to suggest better alternatives!)
Not sure if it's relevant but the USBCmera class is a java class with calls to a native library

USBCamera looks like something that shouldn't be accessible by your composables in the first place. Put it in a repository and only expose its data by a Flow when it becomes available (like, after the initialization).
Modifications of USBCamera should only be exposed in the repository as callbacks. Make sure to design the API surface to adhere to the principles of Unidirectional Data Flow.
Now your view model can use that repository to convert the flow into a StateFlow for your composables to collect. The view model will also expose the necessary repository functions that the composables should be able to access, like this:
Button(onClick = { viewModel.setCameraGain(10) }) {}

Your composables won't have to worry now about the initialization state of the camera, they just retrieve data from the view model and call the functions from the view model as they like. The view model is just the conduit to the repository, and the repository handles all the dirty work. There you can make sure that USBCamera#setGain is only called when it is initialized.

Thanks @Leviathan, that sounds like solid advice. And it does solve the problem. However, I'm really curious why my original approach doesn't work?

In the code you provided camera is always null. You say it is initialized in some other thread but you didn't show us how that thread is started or how exactly that initialization - including eventually setting the camera property - is actually done. It is also unclear what exactly "accessing it using LocalContext" means. Without that information I cannot really tell you why it didn't work. The answer I've given simplifies your problem and confines it to a single class (the repository). That way it should be less error prone and easier to understand when something goes wrong.

Firstly this is not a jetpak/compose issue. It's also not strictly a nullable issue either
I misunderstood the concept of references and pass by reference in Java/Kotlin. For whatever reason, I assumed that objects are passed by reference, and by that I mean like by pointer as you might in C/C++
As I understand it now, in Java you have references to objects but these are always passed by value. Java only does pass by value
So, it seems to me, even though you can, there is no point passing a nullable that is null, because it can only ever be re-assigned (either locally or outside the function it is passed to), at which point it isn't referring to the same object any more
